# Using tag attributes for filtering tags in simple-framework

Tags: java, android, xml, simple-framework

Now I have this code:

```
@ElementListUnion({
        @ElementList(entry = "broom", type = Broom.class, inline = true),
        @ElementList(entry = "update", type = Update.class, inline = true)
})
private List<Task> tasks;
```

With this code I can write in xml these tags:

```
<broom/>
<update/>
```

and different classes for this tags will be used.

Now I want to write this xml:

```
<entry name="broom"/>
<entry name="update"/>
```

Is it possible to change my annotations, so for these two tags will be used to different classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to change my annotations, so for these two tags will be used to different classes?

This is not possible, but with a `Converter` you can solve this.

There you can implement the *"if attribute is XY, then ..."* part.

Please see here:

- [Deserialize XML elements to different types, based on attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854774/deserialize-xml-elements-to-different-types-based-on-attribute/25900583#25900583)
- [demarshalling an xml where attributes determine type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24563401/demarshalling-an-xml-where-attributes-determine-type/24620147#24620147)